# Woocommerce open product link in new tab after "endless scroll" with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have managed to get all product links on my Woocommerce site to open in a new tab, however, I am using endless scroll with ajax for loading more products and the products that get loaded via endless scroll does not open in a new tab when clicking on them.

Here is my current code for opening products in a new tab;

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
add_action ( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'chr_function_open_new_tab', 10 );
function chr_function_open_new_tab() {
echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link">';
}
```

Any help with this is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think that your remove_action cannot take an action. That's why it gives a trouble. So try this code:

```html
add_action('init',function(){ remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 ); } ,0);
function chr_function_open_new_tab() {
    echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link">';
}
```

Second Other Solution, you can do it with simple jQuery

```html
add_action('wp_footer',function(){
if ( has_term( 'stone', 'product_cat' ) ) {
echo '<script>

//for existing content
jQuery(".woocommerce-LoopProduct-link").attr("target","_blank");

//for content part which comes from AJAX
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
jQuery(".woocommerce-LoopProduct-link").attr("target","_blank");
});
</script>';
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead try to use this dedicated filter hook for add to cart button:

```
// Change loop add to cart ajax button to a linked button to single product pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart', 20, 2 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart( $html, $product ) {
    $link = $product->get_permalink();
    $text = __("Read More", "woocommerce");
    return '<a href="' . $link . '" target="_blank" class="button alt add_to_cart_button">' . $text . '</a>';
}
```

And here for the product link:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'replace_template_loop_product_link_open', 1 );
function replace_loop_product_link() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item','woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
    add_action ( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'new_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
}

function new_loop_product_link_open() {
    global $product;

    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $product->get_permalink() ) . '" target="_blank" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> But in your case, it could not work as expected, depending on how your custom ajax functionality is implemented. As the problem remains for products loaded via ajax, the `target="_blank"` need to be implemented in the corresponding script too.
>
> **At this point nobody can help you more as we can't guess how this functionality is built.**

Comment: Sorry, it works, but only for "add to cart" button, can I get it so also the picture links to new tab if clicked?

Comment: @ChrisB Updated - But in your case, it could not work as expected, depending on how your custom ajax functionality is implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the updated script, I can give you a link to the site if that can help you see how the ajax is built? I have not built it myself, but it's through a theme.

Comment: @ChrisB Sorry, no it will not help… You should better ask themes authors in this case.